# EXCEL VBA/ SELEIUM "Click on a Button" <> Element not Found error

Tags: excel, vba, xpath, element

I keep getting error when trying to click on a "Download button" I am able to navigate the page. But when it comes time to click on the .xlsx download button (button-1127) it cant find the element. Is there a better way ?? Excuse my crude VBA coding.. Only thing i can think of is it because it needs to be hovered over before its clickable. In Chrome inspect i do see the class change for btn-pressed and hover. I have tried xpath and same result.

The Elements are in iframe

```
<iframe id="uxtabiframe-1061-iframeEl">
```

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="button-1127"]
```

Element:

```
<a class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item uft-id-gridexportexcel x-btn-gridtoolbar-toolbar-small" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" role="button" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" id="button-1127" tabindex="10910" data-componentid="button-1127" style="left: 2794px; margin: 0px; top: 3px;"><span id="button-1127-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-gridtoolbar-toolbar-small "><span id="button-1127-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-gridtoolbar-toolbar-small  x-btn-no-text x-btn-icon x-btn-icon-left x-btn-button-center "><span id="button-1127-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-gridtoolbar-toolbar-small exportExcel " style=""></span><span id="button-1127-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-gridtoolbar-toolbar-small">&nbsp;</span></span></span></a>
```

Code:
'

```
Set d = New ChromeDriver
With d
    
    .SetPreference "download.default_directory", DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY
    .SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True 'safeguard
    .SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False 'safeguard
    .Get URL
    .FindElementById("textfield-1034-inputEl").Click
    .SendKeys ("*******")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
    .FindElementById("textfield-1035-labelEl").Click
    .SendKeys ("******")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
    .FindElementById("button-1036").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"))
    .FindElementById("tab-1064-btnEl").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
    .FindElementById("button-1127-btnEl").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
    
    d.Quit
End With
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to switch the iframe to allow to see the elements.

Example :

```
.SwitchToFrame ("uxtabiframe-1061-iframeEl")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:2"))
.FindElementById("button-1127").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"))
```